# Replace an array of objects with another array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a content of an array1 that i want to replace with the content of another array2, so at the end, the array1 will have the same content as the array2 but i want to keep the same references and indexes of array1:

```
let array1 = [
 {  book : { id : 2, authorId : 3} } ,
 {  book : { id : 3, authorId : 3} },
 {  book : { id : 4, authorId : 3} }
]

 let array2 = [
 {  book : { id : 2, authorId : 3} } ,
 {  book : { id : 3, authorId : 2} },
 {  book : { id : 4, authorId : 2} }
]
```

I tried this :

```
[].splice.apply(array1), [0, array1.length].concat(array2));
```

but i still have the same content of array1 instead of array2

The result expected for array1 should be a copy of array2, which means:

```
[
     {  book : { id : 2, authorId : 3} } ,
     {  book : { id : 3, authorId : 2} },
     {  book : { id : 4, authorId : 2} }
    ]
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just use a json copy:

```
array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
array1 = [...array2]
```

Comment: this wont work if i want to filter the array1 first ex : array1.filter(x=>x.book.id == 2) = [...array2]

Comment: You mean use array2's elements to replace array1's one by one ?